# Скоратить пуш в объект

Tags: javascript

Есть такой объект

```
var linePositions = {"x": [], "y": []};
```

Вот как я в него пушу:

```
linePositions.x.push(line.attr("x2"));
linePositions.y.push(line.attr("y2"));
```

Вопрос. Могу ли я как-то сократить код и пушить используя одну сроку и один вызов?

Comment: Наверное можно извратиться и что-нибудь придумать, но читаемость кода уменьшится, скорее всего. Чем вас не устраивает такая запись?

Comment: Да меня в целом устраивает, ищу варианты просто для удобства

Answer (score 2):

```
var linePositions = {
  "x": [], 
  "y": [],
  push: function(x, y) {
    this.x.push(x);
    this.y.push(y);
  }
};

linePositions.push(line.attr("x2"), line.attr("y2"));
```